# How to preg_match() a string and output all results into an array?

Tags: php, preg-match

I want to output all matching results into an array.
I'm only able to output one word and not both.

```
$input = "I like to eat <cookies> with <coke>.";
$output = [];

preg_match('~<(.*?)>~', $input, $output);
echo $output[1];
```

It should result with something like:

```
$output = ["cookies", "coke"];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were really close.  Use `preg_match_all()` instead.

```
$input = "I like to eat <cookies> with <coke>.";
$output = [];

preg_match_all('~<(.*?)>~', $input, $output);
print_r($output[1]);
```

Comment: Why it needs to be `$output[1]` and not just `$output[]` ? I also just realized when i type `$output[0]` it outputs `<cookies>`.

Comment: Here is the docs for `preg_match_all()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php  It has to do with the matches.  The [0] index is usually a full pattern match. [1] would be the capture match minus the pattern.  Say I search `<b>(.*?)</b>`.  The [0] would have `<b>Bold Text</b>` and [1] would have `Bold Text`

Comment: Is it possible to use a preg_match inside a preg_match? For example `$input = "I like to eat <"cookies","apples"> with <"coke","water">.";` So it would output 2 arrays with `$food = ["cookies","apples"] $drinks = ["coke","water"]`

Comment: @DamianToczek `0` is the full match. `1` is the first capture group. Each index is a capture group, after the full match which is always `0`.

Comment: @DamianToczek I'd use `preg_match_all`, then iterate over the result with http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php for that example.

Comment: @userWithManyNumbers I'm not using csv files or anything.

Comment: @DamianToczek `"coke","water"` is a CSV with 2 values. Try the linked doc.